# Web Flow view resolver problems

Tags: spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I have a sample application with web flows in a number of jars (extensions) and the configuration is loaded from the classpath this works fine. But I'm struggling with the view resolver configuration that will load the JSP's from the same location as the flow definitions on the classpath?

so I have the following folder structure on the classpath
MEAT-INF/config-webflow/ext1/ flow definition and JSP's for flow extension 1 are here

The web flow configuration works fine as I set this as `flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices" base-path="classpath*:/META-INF/config-webflow">`

But as yet I can not come up with a view resolver configuration to load the JSP's

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I discovered that you get the desired behaviour by NOT setting the normal Spring MVC 'viewResolver' bean on the MvcViewFactoryCreator.

```
<flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" development="true" />

<beans:bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator" />
```